# Choosing BLE broadcast interval

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

My IOT device has two functionalities.
1. It provides load/weight data when the weight is applied
2. It is also used for tracking the location of an item to which it is attached.

My battery capacity is 150mAH. What is the best broadcast interval I should use?  If I use longer broadcast interval like 2 seconds, it will mean weight has to be applied for a longer period to get the weight data which is inconvenient for the user. However, too frequent broadcast can cause drain on the battery when it is used for tracking. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question but is kind of subject to opinion, but perhaps there is a 'best practice' for this that might be useful to have a discussion on. In my iOS application I have a broadcast interval *and* a scan interval. The broadcast interval is the time in which the application is 'advertising' the BLE data and the scan interval is the time in which the application will be (obviously) 'scanning' for the BLE data. My interval values are as follow:

**Broadcast** for 15 seconds - then wait for 15 seconds until next broadcast.

**Scan** for 5 seconds - then wait for 25 seconds until next scan.

My application broadcasts and scans for continuous updates from all other applications in the area. In this paradigm the application will scan for and receive updates twice a minute (or so). The broadcast will happen for 15 seconds then wait for the same amount of time, and this will happen every 30 seconds as well. The thought being in perfectly synchronized world each application in the area will be updated every 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brandon. In my case the peripheral broadcasts and the phone scans. I am thinking of the following flow, let me know your thoughts.                1.Set the broad cast interval at 500ms for 3 minutes or so.... 2. After 3 minutes go to sleep for 30 seconds. 3. After 30 seconds of sleep time send out an advertisement for 30 seconds at 500 ms interval ...if there is a scan request continue to share data for 3 minutes if not...go back to sleep after 30 seconds.

Comment: If your IOT device is not battery powered I would say that would be okay but might be a little overkill on your 'share' interval. I might keep this at just a 30 second max pairing if I could. I tend to think of BLE as a radio transmission. I broadcast for 30 seconds and wait another 30 seconds until the next transmission. This always making sure who ever is 'tuning in' will get the transmission at least once every minute. But this all depends on your particular requirements. My use case may be different than yours because I am just updating the apps that 'scan' from ones that 'broadcast'.

Comment: So what you are saying is always share only for 30 seconds and no need for 3 minutes. Interesting...I will explore that suggestion for my use case. Thank you!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, in the opposite of a perfect world, your scanner would never detect the beacon with those settings! If you set the scanner to the same settings as the broadcast, then the only time you'll miss is the rare case where both out of sync by exactly 15 seconds. If you increase the scanner to 20:10 and handle duplicate broadcasts, you can ensure no broadcasts are missed! In the current setup, there's roughly a 33% chance (10 second startup window) of the scanner not detecting a particular beacon--ever.